# XNA: Losing Reference When Deleting Class in Project

Tags: c#, reference, xna

I'm new to XNA and C#. I have this problem:

When I add a new windows game library and I make reference in main project everything seems ok. The problem is when I delete class from this new project. I'm losing the reference for this new library and I don't know why.

Is there solution for this?

Comment: Can you show us the code and more details about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you used the correct using statement,

have you added a reference to the other project correctly

does the class exist in the other project

Comment: i can see where is problem now. I was litlle confused about using namespaces. I had wrong namespace in my class. Thanks much for guiding me to righ solution :)